# Model method in Rails controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a model called `Visitor`, which has the following method:

```
def online?
  !Redis.new.get("#{self.auth_token}").nil?
end
```

In my controller, I want to filter all the visitors that are currently online, something like this:

```
@organisation_vistors = Visitor.where(:organisation_id => session[:orga_id], :online => true )
```

Can someone help me with what is the best rails way to achieve this?

Comment: i think you want to access `online?` of visitor class which will be achive by `@visitor.online?`

Comment: `@organisation_vistors.first.online?` try this one

Comment: They work but what I want is the all the visitors that are online. I do not want to query each of them individually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Supposing `online?` is merely a model method and not an attribute on the table, you cannot put that within your SQL request. Filter by that condition after the SQL.

```
@organisation_vistors =
  Visitor
  .where(organisation_id: session[:orga_id])
  .select(&:online?)
```

Comment: This is going to be complicated because it involves querying both your Redis cache and your database to decide if users are a: in the given org and b: online. It's likely that any solution using both of these will scale up badly, leading to poor performance. - This will work, but you may have to rethink it at some point in the future.